# Adding Logic Hooks in Magento?

Tags: magento, hook

Can I ask regarding the topic? Can you add a logic hook in magento or anything like it?
Just tell me straight if it doesn't make sense or I'm just missing something from the Magento Doc's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called 'event observers' in Magento.

See:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: Create an event and then you can have an observer watch for that event.